# Organizing files on my computer into Mediawiki-style categories

Tags: mediawiki

I'd like to organize the files on my computer into Wikimedia-style categories, where files can be added to categories and every file can belong to more than one category. Can this be done using a local MediaWiki server, or is there a better way to do this?

For example, I'd like to add the folder "Javascript experiments" to the category "Programming experiments" as well as "Javascript." I'd also like to put the category "Programming experiments" into the category "Computer programming", and put "Javascript experiments" into the category "programming experiments." Then I'd create a category called "computer science homework" within the category "computer programming."

Comment: Here is a relevant post that I just re-discovered: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/tiddlywiki/ooPDpzWYtVM/discussion

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu and Windows (a dual-boot configuration.) I'll accept solutions that are relevant to either operating system.

Comment: It might be feasible to do this using a local MediaWiki server, by uploading the files to the server. (I'm not sure if I can put folders into categories using MediaWiki, though.)

Comment: What I need to find is a document management system that allows files to be sorted into categories, like MediaWiki categories. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_management_system

Comment: so basically, a tagged file system? see http://stackoverflow.com/q/3263036/1443496